# Rendering Jbuilder view

Tags: jbuilder

I am using rabl for my api calls in rails application. Here is my sample code

```
app.get '/item/:id' do
  @errors = []
  @revisions = []
  request.body.rewind  # in case someone already read it
  @item = Entity.for_owner(params[:id], @user)
  render :rabl, :item_show
end
```

Instead of rabl I want to use jbuilder how can I render here. I have made the view jbuilder view like this `item_show.json.builder`

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.id @item.id
  json.account_id @item.account_id
end
```

Could any one help me how can i render this view.
I tried with `@item.to_json` but it is not rendering jbuilder view.

Comment: I am using this in sinatra app.

Answer (score 3):

tilt-jbuilder supports Sinatra since 0.4.0, and I wrote a sample at https://gist.github.com/a2ikm/5072882 . I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the extension of the template from .builder to .jbuilder